# Confusion between normal distribution and normal approximation

Tags: probability

I have a confusion between understanding the normal distribution and normal approximation. I tried to solve the following question but I am unable to understand that what this question is asking for. If anyone can please solve this question

A certain characteristic is present in 4% of a given population.  If X represents the number in a sample of size n who have the characteristic, the X has a binomial distribution.  How large must n (the number of trials) be in order that the normal approximation to the distribution of X be valid

Comment: Please provide details of your attempted solution and state exactly what it is that you don’t understand

Comment: I don't understand the difference between binomial distribution and normal approximation. And, also what this question is asking whether to solve binomial distribution or normal approximation?

Comment: You can use the normal distribution to approximate a binomial distribution, usually when N is large and p is close to 0.5 such that $X\sim N(np, npq)$. Just make sure to follow the definitions closely

Comment: P close to 0.5 isn't important, what is important is that $np$ and $nq$ are both large.

Comment: How was this explained to you previously? Even if you did not understand the explanation, it is useful to say what it was and exactly at what point in the explanation you got lost. Also, what criteria were you given to decide whether a normal approximation is valid? (Note: details like these should be edited into the question, not merely written in comments.)

Comment: So, is there any solution to this question please?

Comment: Can anyone please solve this question?

Comment: Most likely you have been given specific instructions for how exactly to solve this problem, because it is subjective (how good is good enough?) Most likely they amount to some threshold for $\min \{ np,n(1-p) \}$, so in your problem you need $n>25$ times some number that doesn't depend on $p$. There are numerous reasonable values of this constant depending on how accurate you care about; $30$ is easily big enough for most purposes, but $10$ might be big enough as well depending on your standards.